# In JS/React, how to store array properties into new array to display new array values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, loops

I have 3 different states `companies`, `projects`, and `releases`.

```
this.state = {
  companies: [],
  projects: [],
  releases: []
}
```

After doing a fetch and updating all 3 states, they all contains data:

```
componentWillMount() {
  getCompanys().then(companies => {
    const projectPromises = companies.map((company) => {
      getProjects(company).then(projects => {
        const releasePromises = projects.map((project) => {
          return getReleases(project).then(releases => {
            if(projects.length > 0 || releases > 0) {
              this.setState({
                companies: companies,
                projects: projects,
                releases: releases
              });
            }
          })
        })
      })
    });
  })
}
```

Here's a sample output of their current data:
[image: States output]

Now, my question is if I wanted to create a new array and store just **company_name**, **company's description**, **project_name**, **project's description**, **release_name**, and **release's description**, how would I do that? Is it possible to store just these information into new array and then only loop the new array to display those information so I don't have to loop an array of all 3 states?

This is what I would like to have for my desired output:

```
newArray = [
    {
        company_name: 'IBM',
        company_description: 'Comp description',
        project_name: 'Project 101',
        project_description: 'Proj description',
        release_name: 'Release 101',
        release_description: 'Rel description'
    }
]
```

Full output data:

[image: enter code here]

Comment: :) Your code looks like a gun.

Comment: Is all the information from each array going to have the same id's. Basically will company[0] have the project info from project[0]?

Comment: Based on what condition you will merge 3 different data in one object for whole collection.. ?

Comment: @BradeyWhitlock - yes, company[0] will have the project info from project[0]. Both projects are associated with company[0] and a release is associated with project.

Comment: @RyuH - ok then I believe my answer will work. You might need to tweak variable names as I copied your example output for the variable names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look through the length of company if they have the same info in all of them. For instance if `company[0]` has your compnay_name and company_description and `projects[0]` has project_name and project_description for the same company you can do something like this.

```
var newArray = [];
for(var i = 0; i < company.length; i++){
   newArray.push(
      {
          company_name: this.state.companies[i].company_name,
          company_description: this.state.companies[i].company_description,
          project_name: this.state.projects[i].project_name,
          project_description: this.state.project[i].project_description,
          release_name: this.state.releases[i].release_name,
          release_description: this.state.releases[i].release_description
      }
   )
}
```

Then do whatever you want with that array. Add it to state to use else where or what have you.

Comment: I just tried this but the array is returning as blank with no data

Comment: You'll want to do this after you have the data in the three arrays. You said in your question that you are getting the data into the array I believe. You can make a function that has my code and run it after the state is set for all the arrays

Comment: Got it Bradey! Thank you so much! I just realized, the company array only contains project id, but not the project name and description. That's why I am only able to access company name into newArray. Since project id is referenced in the company array, is it possible to somehow display the project name and project description into newArray? I am getting undefined for both of them with `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

Comment: actually, never mind your solution is working! I am able to display project's info and release's info just fine! Thank you for the help Bradey, really appreciated!

Comment: No problem, glad I can help!